# Good USB wireless adapter for ubuntu [available in the UK]?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, wireless-networking

I currently have an Ubuntu Jaunty setup using a Netgear Wg111T usb adapter that craps out regularly and also has to be disconnected during boot up.  It's annoying enough that I'd like to get a new one.

I'd like one that just works (rather than ndiswrapper) so I can support hardware manufacturers who are Linux friendly.

Any recommendations for wireless usb adapters commonly available in the UK?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which adapter did you settle for?

Comment: I gave up.  It isn't the adapters.  It's the truckload of bugs in ubuntu's wireless (un)support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find http://www.linuxemporium.co.uk/products/wireless/ a useful resource. A friend of mine bought one from there for use with a Linux laptop and has had no problems with it. Not the cheapest, but you've got more guarantee of decent Linux support than you'll get elsewhere.

---

*Edit:* One thing to be aware of when following specific recommendations is that it is not unusual for two devices with *exactly* the same model number (and sometimes no other easily identifiable differences) to have different versions of the chipset and it can be that one works well with Linux and the other doesn't reliably (or at all). Worse, it is not unheard of for externally identical (including model numbers) devices to have different chipsets altogether.

If you do end up buying a device online that *should* work will with Linux (as per someone's recommendation) but doesn't, remember your right to a cooling off period of seven days from receiving the goods during which you can get a full refund. See [this recent BBC article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/business/8245799.stm), and [this one too](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/theoneshow/consumer/2009/08/27/get_your_refund_distance_selli.html), for some detail on that.

Comment: Consider before you buy another adapter that there may be improved drivers for your old one in Ubuntu 9.10 as there will be an updated Kernel.

Comment: I can't wait a month.

Comment: You could throw caution to the wind a little and try the beta.

Comment: Just tried it on a laptop and it worked instantly with the built in adapter.  Now I just have to figure out how to get it to upgrade from a CD and I'll try it on the desktop in question.

Comment: The easiest way may be to take a full backup of the machine in question and do an in-place upgrade. I believe the GUI tools support this operation though I've never done it under Ubuntu (going from release to release in Debian using the command line tools has proven reliable for me in the past and the process should be pretty similar).

Comment: I did the upgrade using the alternate cd and it appeared to work but it didn't add a grub entry (I kept the old grub since the Grub 2 had problems with dual booting in the beta) and when I sorted that it wouldn't load Gnome.  Ah well.  The Yak is half shaved.

Comment: The problem is now sorted and I would like add an extra recommendation for the linux emporium.  They are in the same city as me and I met one of the operators and he gave me an edimax usb adapter (like the one mentioned by The Journeyman geek) that worked perfectly.  My wife is thrilled the bright blue cable is gone.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to be absolutely specific?

http://www.edimax.com/en/produce_detail.php?pd_id=8&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=44

ralink RT73 based (supported out of the box on at least intrepid and jaunty), and of course, detachable antennae, in case.

Comment: Ultimately this is what ended up working.  I actually met one the guys who works at the Linux Emporium (it is in the same city as me) at a Ruby User Group meeting and he gave me one.  Worked instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I think using ndiswrapper utility isnt that bad

Great if you find a better solution than mine, 
But if u HAVE to use ndiswrapper NETGEAR WG111 is a great option.
I see u use WG111 already, maybe it crashes bcos of a bad driver.

Try this one...

get the zip file from :
[**ndis drivers for wg111**](http://kbserver.netgear.com/release_notes/D102534.asp)

**NOTE** : dont use the .inf file in the mother folder, instead find the correct .inf file in the **ndis5** folder

thats it